# Adding custom emails to BCC for specific Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, woocommerce, custom-fields, email-notifications, bcc

In Woocommerce, I have a custom email template (id = 'wc_course_order') that sends when a specific product (an online course) is purchased.

Below I use a hooked function that adds recipients based on order metadata from custom fields (i.e. "Student Email"). It's based on [this thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49663093/3730754).

How can I add these recipients as BCC and grab their "First Name" field and add that to the body of the email, especially given that two quantities of the course product may be purchased together with two different student names/emails?

The row output is:

```
"meta_data": [{"id": 652,
   "key": "First Name - 1",
    "value": "John"},
    {"id": 653,
    "key": "Last Name - 1",
    "value": "Doe"},
    {"id": 654,
    "key": "Student Email - 1",
    "value": "johndoe@example.com"}]
```

And then for an additional student registered in the same purchase, output would be "key": "First Name - 2", "value": "Jane", and "... - 3" etc.

**I realize that it can be split in two questions:**

1. How do **I grab their names** in addition to the emails (which I already grabbed, see full function below)?
2. How do I **add their email addresses as BCC** instead of appending the $recipients as regular "TO:"?

The full function that I am using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_recipient_wc_course_order', 'student_email_notification', 10, 2 );
function student_email_notification( $recipient, $order) {
    $student_emails = array();
    $enroll_num = 0;

    // Loop though  Order IDs
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ){
        $course_qty = $item_data->get_quantity();
        $q = 1;
        while ( $q <= $course_qty){
            // Get the student email
            $enroll_num++;
            $student_email = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Student Email - '.$enroll_num, true );
            if( ! empty($student_email) )
                $student_emails[] = $student_email; // Add email to the array
            $q++;
        }
    }

    // If any student email exist we add it
    if( count($student_emails) > 0 ){
        // Remove duplicates (if there is any)
        $student_emails = array_unique($student_emails);
        // Add the emails to existing recipients
    $recipient .= ',' . implode( ',', $student_emails );
    }
    return $recipient;
}
```

Can this all be done within `functions.php` or should this be done in the separate email template file I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'wc_course_order' is a custom email notification ID that I can't really test it with it (so for testing purpose I have commented it, when testing the function myself)…

Using the same way than you to get the email, I suppose that I am getting the **first and last name** in the code below *(but I am not absolutely sure)*…

Now to add this emails as BCC, you will have to change of hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_headers', 'student_email_notification', 20, 3 );
function student_email_notification( $header, $email_id, $order ) {
    // Only for 'wc_course_order' notification
    if( 'wc_course_order' != $email_id ) return $header; 

    $student_emails = array();
    $enroll_num = 0;

    // Loop though  Order IDs
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data ){
        $course_qty = $item_data->get_quantity();
        $q = 1;
        while ( $q <= $course_qty){
            $enroll_num++;
            // Get the student full Name
            $full_name     = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'First Name - '.$enroll_num, true );
            $full_name    .= ' ' . wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Last Name - '.$enroll_num, true );
            // Get the student email
            $student_email = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'Student Email - '.$enroll_num, true );
            if( ! empty($student_email) && $full_name != ' ' )
                // Format the name and the email and set it in an array
                $student_emails[] = utf8_decode($full_name . ' <' . $student_email . '>'); // Add name + email to the array
            $q++;
        }
    }

    // If any student email exist we add it
    if( count($student_emails) > 0 ){
        // Remove duplicates (if there is any)
        $student_emails = array_unique($student_emails);
        // Add the emails to existing recipients
        $header .= 'Bcc: ' . implode(',', $student_emails) . "\r\n";
    }
    return $header;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works 
*(I can't really test your code at 100%, but it should work, I hope)*.

---

Related: [How to get order ID in woocommerce_email_headers hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738772/how-to-get-order-id-in-woocommerce-email-headers-hook/39741446#39741446)

Comment: It works once I make sure to have an email address in the "To" field as well (won't send if I just have in the BCC).

Comment: But is there also a way to send the `$full_name` to the email template to use in the body of the email, such as "Dear `$full_name`, "?
I use `<p style="color:white;"><?php printf( __( 'This was purchased by %s.', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ); ?></p>` to get and print the purchaser's name.

Comment: @calwex718 Woocommerce send by default an email to the customer (the "TO")… You have to remove your other related code and use only this answer code… So it will works as intended…

Comment: Is there a way to add those email addresses into the body of the email? I have a template and have tried using $get_recipient and $recipient in my email template but it doesn't pass them. I am using this function in functions.php and a custom email plugin to generate the email if the specific course product is entered. (I've followed up with another question, though it's still a follow-up of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419736/woocommerce-emails-sending-multiple-emails-based-on-product-count)